# How to have 2 commands to the same toolbar item in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, icommand

`ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Save", null, () => (BindingContext as AddPersonViewModel).SaveCommand.Execute(null)));` so thats my toolbar item code. each time i press the Save btn then savecommand.execute!

I want to add one more command to this button. I would like each time i click the Save button 1st to save the data and then to navigate to anothe page ! How can i do that? Thanks

(You can only bind one command to a toolbaritem or any control in XForms that supports ICommand.)

Answer (score 0):

aggregate two commands with another command

```
public ICommand SaveAndNavigateCommand {
get{
   return new Command(()=>{
       SaveCommand.Execute(null);
       NavigateCommand.Execute(null);
   });
}
}
```

aggregate two commands with another command

Navigate command depends on MVVM framework that you use. If you do not use any, then the code will look like this:

```
class AddPersonViewModel{

readonly INavigation _navigation;

public AddPersonViewModel(INavigation navigation){
   _navigation = navigation;
}

public ICommand NavigateCommand {
get{
   return new Command(()=>{
       _navigation.PushAsync(new ContentPage()); //Insert here page that you want navigate to 
   });
}
}

}
```

And then, when creating your view model, assuming that you create it in page class:

```
class AddPersonPage: Page{
    public AddPersonPage(){
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new AddPersonViewModel(this.Navigation);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! but how my NavigateCommand would look like? `protected async void Navigate()
        {
            ???
        }`

Comment: Depending on MVVM framework that you use. Which one do you use?